# Compare two array object and remove values

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays with objects in it which looks similar to:

```
let comp1 = [
    { optionKey: 'option1', displayName: '' },
    { optionKey: 'option2', displayName: '' },
    { optionKey: 'option3', displayName: '' },
    { optionKey: 'option4', displayName: '' },
    { optionKey: 'option5', displayName: '' },
    { optionKey: 'option6', displayName: '' },
    { optionKey: 'option7', displayName: '' },
  ];
let comp2 = [
    { option1Options: [] },
    { option2Options: [] },
    { option3Options: ['On', 'Off'] },
    { option4Options: ['Auto ', 'Off'] },
    { option5Options: [] },
    { option6Options: [] },
  ];
```

What I wanted to do was, if the value of each key in comp2's length in 0, I want to remove that key without `Option` index removed from `comp1`. So far, I was able to do is if each array has equal length

```js
let comp1 = [
    { optionKey: 'option1', displayName: '' },
    { optionKey: 'option2', displayName: '' },
    { optionKey: 'option3', displayName: '' },
    { optionKey: 'option4', displayName: '' },
    { optionKey: 'option5', displayName: '' },
    { optionKey: 'option6', displayName: '' },
    { optionKey: 'option7', displayName: '' },
  ];
let comp2 = [
    { option1Options: [] },
    { option2Options: [] },
    { option3Options: ['On', 'Off'] },
    { option4Options: ['Auto ', 'Off'] },
    { option5Options: [] },
    { option6Options: [] },
  ];
  
comp1.forEach(function (item) {
    var index = comp2.findIndex(function (item2, i) {
        return item2[item.optionKey + 'Options'] !== undefined;
    });
    if (index !== -1) {
        if (comp2[index][item.optionKey + 'Options'].length === 0) {
            comp1.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
});

console.log(comp1)
```

But in my case `comp1` and `comp2` length are different. How should I remove it by the key's value in `comp1`? Any help on this is apricated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're splicing the array you're iterating over inside the `forEach`, which results in the array skipping the next element. For example, if you had items 1-2-3-4-5-6, and the test being performed would mean that all should be removed, you'd first remove 1, skip 2, remove 3, skip 4, remove 5, and skip 6.

While it would be possible to refactor so that the indices aren't creating this problem (such as a `for` loop), a better approach would be to iterate fully through `comp2` first, identify the options to remove, then call `.filter` on `comp1`.

```js
let comp1 = [
    { optionKey: 'option1', displayName: '' },
    { optionKey: 'option2', displayName: '' },
    { optionKey: 'option3', displayName: '' },
    { optionKey: 'option4', displayName: '' },
    { optionKey: 'option5', displayName: '' },
    { optionKey: 'option6', displayName: '' },
    { optionKey: 'option7', displayName: '' },
  ];
let comp2 = [
    { option1Options: [] },
    { option2Options: [] },
    { option3Options: ['On', 'Off'] },
    { option4Options: ['Auto ', 'Off'] },
    { option5Options: [] },
    { option6Options: [] },
  ];
  
const optionsToRemove = comp2
  .filter(obj => !Object.values(obj)[0].length)
  .map(obj => Object.keys(obj)[0].replace(/Options$/, ''));
const output = comp1.filter(
  ({ optionKey }) => !optionsToRemove.includes(optionKey)
);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and to fully explain the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) comp1 using a [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) call to check if any options arrays exist in comp2. Here using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to avoid nonexistent elements in comp2

```js
let comp1 = [{ optionKey: 'option1', displayName: '' }, { optionKey: 'option2', displayName: '' }, { optionKey: 'option3', displayName: '' }, { optionKey: 'option4', displayName: '' }, { optionKey: 'option5', displayName: '' }, { optionKey: 'option6', displayName: '' }, { optionKey: 'option7', displayName: '' },];
let comp2 = [{ option1Options: [] }, { option2Options: [] }, { option3Options: ['On', 'Off'] }, { option4Options: ['Auto ', 'Off'] }, { option5Options: [] }, { option6Options: [] },];

const result = comp1.filter(o =>
  comp2.some(option => option[`${o.optionKey}Options`]?.length > 0)
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple combination of `filter()` and `some()` should get you there:

```js
const comp1 = [
  { optionKey: 'option1', displayName: '' },
  { optionKey: 'option2', displayName: '' },
  { optionKey: 'option3', displayName: '' },
  { optionKey: 'option4', displayName: '' },
  { optionKey: 'option5', displayName: '' },
  { optionKey: 'option6', displayName: '' },
  { optionKey: 'option7', displayName: '' },
];

const comp2 = [
  { option1Options: [] },
  { option2Options: [] },
  { option3Options: ['On', 'Off'] },
  { option4Options: ['Auto ', 'Off'] },
  { option5Options: [] },
  { option6Options: [] },
];

const result = comp1.filter(({optionKey}) => comp2.some(v => v[`${optionKey}Options`]?.length));

console.log(result);
```